# PHP warning message (file_get_contents())

Tags: php

I tried moving a website on my work server and I got the following warning messages:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/theworks/public_html/24easy/locations_listing.php on line 51

Also this warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=44.426767399999996,26.1025384&destination=Bacau+Comanesti+Strada+Republicii+18&alternatives=true&sensor=true): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/theworks/public_html/24easy/locations_listing.php on line 51

The script should calculate the distance using Google Distance Matrix for each location and show it on the website. The problem is that I have nothing on line 51 that would cause such an error, it's just a simple query `$row` variable.

```
if ($row_promotions > 0){
```

(copied from 49 to 55, just a bunch of html before and after for 20 rows or such)

This would be the code that in my opinion causes problems:

```
$address = $row['Judet'] . '+' . $row['Localitate'] . '+' . $row['Strada'] . '+' . $row['Numar'];

$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);

$fullurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $origin . '&destination=' . $address .  '&alternatives=true&sensor=true';

$json_a = json_decode((file_get_contents($fullurl)),true); 

$whole_data[] = array("id" => $row["id"], "name" => $row["name"], "logo" => $row["logo"], "value" => $json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value'],  "text" => $json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']);
```

The only `file_get_contents()` I have is the one I showed here and it's on line 101. Any idea why this happens?

**Note: used to work in January on a different host**

Comment: You have `file_get_contents` in this line `json_decode((file_get_contents($fullurl)),true); `. That's why it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: ah, damn, search the document for file_get_contents and it didn't returned anything, probably had a typo while searching... anyway that file_get_contents is on line 101

Comment: It's disabled by your hosting provider. Ask them to enable it by setting allow_URL_fopen = 1

Comment: @AlexTartan No. Don't ask them to enable `allow_url_fopen`, that's a security risk, and rightly so. Instead, use `cURL` to execute your request and parse the returned data as JSON.

Comment: It's just for a test, the client that has this app reported slow loading time when it has more than 20 entries. Wanted to test it on our own server to see if it has something to do with the free host he currently uses.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It's not a security risk if you know what you're getting. And the google maps API seems pretty safe to me. It is indeed slower that curl, but in this case it's a pretty straight forward call.

Comment: @AlexTartan In your opinion could the slow loading times be caused by the free hosting?

Comment: @MateiPanchios This is a pretty big subject and with no details it's hard to say.  Free hostings can indeed lead to high loading times. Paid hostings can guarantee a minimum bandwidth, provide an SSD storage... and more.

Comment: Guess I'll find out as soon as my Project Manager changes the setting so I can test it out. If you want you can post a answer to this question so I can accept it. :)